# Apache proxypass configuration for Apache and JBoss application installed on same server node

Tags: apache, proxypass

If I hit - http://10.157.128.170/oneapp  application should load index.html from Apache content

And **ALL** API calls like http://10.157.128.170:25003/oneapp/*  (where * could be any API Call) should redirect calls to JBOSS on port :25003/oneapp

What could be the Apache configuration for this requirement ?

My current Configuration is :

```
ProxyPassMatch      ^/oneapp/$            !
ProxyPass            /oneapp/index.html   !
ProxyPass            /oneapp              http://10.157.128.170:25003/oneapp
ProxyPassReverse     /oneapp              http://10.157.128.170:25003/oneapp
```

where I need to hit : http://10.157.128.170/index.html for going to index.html but I need that to be http://10.157.128.170/oneapp

File I've on Apache Content directory

```
index.html
app.css
app.js
images
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a trailing slash to fix the issue

```
ProxyPassMatch      ^/oneapp/$            !
ProxyPass            /oneapp/index.html   !
ProxyPass /oneapp/ http://10.157.128.170:25003/oneapp/
ProxyPassReverse /oneapp/ http://10.157.128.170:25003/oneapp/
```

Also make sure that mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http are enabled.